# Batch file to rename spaces with a dot, except the - part and have it lowercase

Tags: windows, rename, batch-rename

I am trying to rename a file from `The Big Bang Theory - The Prom Equivalency.mp4` to `the.big.bang.theory-the.prom.equivalency.mp4` with a batch script. Here's what I've got so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%f IN (%*) DO (
    set filename=%%~nf
    set filename=!filename: =.!
    set filename=!filename: .-.=-!
    rem uncomment for debugging.
    rem if not "!filename!"=="%%~nf" ECHO RENAME "%%~dpnxf" "!filename!%%~xf" >> "%TEMP%\test.txt"
    rem comment for debugging.
    if not "!filename!"=="%%~nf" RENAME "%%~dpnxf" "!filename!%%~xf"
)
```

The file I get is `The.Big.Bang.Theory.-.The.Prom.Equivalency.mp4`.

What is the magic trick to not let it put dots on both sides of `-` and how can I work into the script the lowercase command?

Comment: Why is the question tagged with "bash-scripting"? Are you looking for a bash script or not?

Comment: Perhaps irrelevant, but I'd love to know ***why*** you want to do this... Leaving someone at the other end of the presumably usenet/torrent process with the job of swapping them all back to spaces... Spaces survive usenet/torrent these days

Comment: Tetsujin: Because I download flv files straight from the CBS site and use another batch script to change container from flv to mp4. I have a shared mediaserver for the whole family, which is then accessed by 3 Apple TVs. Then by renaming the files as such its easier to sort and find. Now I have combined the other script with this one, and thanks to you guys everything goes smooth and automated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <strike>What is the magic trick to not let it put dots on both sides of the dash?</strike>

Let’s get back to that.

> How do I get rid of the dots on both sides of the dash?

Change your

```
set filename=!filename: .-.=-!
```

statement to

```
set filename=!filename:.-.=-!
```

because, they way you have it now, you’re looking for (space, dot, dash, dot),
and that sequence isn’t present.

---

OK, now,

> What is the magic trick to not let it put dots on both sides of the dash?

Just reverse the order of your `:`…`=` statements (and tweak the dash one appropriately).

```
set filename=!filename: - =-!
set filename=!filename: =.!
```

This way, you *eliminate* the spaces around the dash before you change the inter-word spaces to dots.

---

> “how can I work into the script the lowercase command?”

Well, you *could* do

```
set filename=!filename:A=a!
set filename=!filename:B=b!
set filename=!filename:C=c!
        ⋮
```

which isn’t very elegant. 
But it’s been pointed out to me that this can be done just as well as

```
set filename=!filename:a=a!
set filename=!filename:b=b!
set filename=!filename:c=c!
        ⋮
```

because the `:`…`=`… string-matching is done in a case-insensitive way
(for example, `:q=ent` will change “sqimQal” into “sentimental”). 
So, adapting Magoo’s answer to [Convert filename from upper case to lower …](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17752585/3960947), we can simplify that to

```
for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    set filename=!filename:%%a=%%a!
)
```

Comment: There is an elegant solution : see Magoo's answer to [convert filename from lower case to upper case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751184/convert-filename-in-a-folder-from-upper-case-to-lower-case-windows-command-prom). Easy applicable vice-versa as well, simply changing the `(A B C ...` to `(a b c ...`